# Set notebook sections one level up

Tags: performance-tuning, front-end, notebooks, cells

Suppose I have a notebook filled with many chapters, sections, subsections, subsubsections and so on. Instead of changing the style of each of them manually, is there a clever way to set all or part of them one level up?

What I mean is changing the left to the right.
[image]

Comment: Yes, there is. Now, what this will look like will depend on what you want to do, exactly, which I couldn't entirely get from the question. Can you give an example of the desired behavior?

Comment: @b3m2a1 Thanks. Updated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's an overkill, but very clean answer:

```
withHiddenChanges[nb_, expr_] :=
  Internal`WithLocalSettings[
   FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`NotebookSuspendScreenUpdates[nb],
   expr,
   FrontEndExecute@FrontEnd`NotebookResumeScreenUpdates[nb]
   ];
withHiddenChanges~SetAttributes~HoldRest;
modifySingleCellStyle[cell_, fn_] :=
  With[{nbr = NotebookRead[cell]},
   NotebookWrite[
    cell,
    Replace[nbr, s_String :> fn[s] , 1],
    AutoScroll -> False
    ]
   ];
modifySingleCellStyle[fn_][cell_] :=
  modifySingleCellStyle[cell, fn];
modifyCellStyles[cells_, modFn_] :=

 Module[{pnbs = GroupBy[cells, ParentNotebook]},
  KeyValueMap[
    withHiddenChanges[#, 
      Map[modifySingleCellStyle[modFn], #2]
      ] &, 
    pnbs
    ];
  ]
```

The sneaky thing I do here is make it so you never see the changes happen. They all happen with notebook updates suspended, so it looks automatic.

If memory isn't an issue, this will be faster:

```
modifyCellStylesBatch[cells_, fn_] :=

  With[{nbrs = NotebookRead[cells]},
   FrontEndExecute@
    MapThread[
     FrontEnd`NotebookWrite[
       #2,
       Replace[#, s_String :> fn[s] , 1],
       AutoScroll -> False
       ] &,
     {nbrs, cells}
     ]
   ];
```

Here's an example:

[image]

Then we run it (I decided after running the first to change the target style):

[image]

Change that `Replace` to implement the logic you want.

You can also see why I turned off the screen updates by running this:

```
cd = CreateDocument[ConstantArray[Cell["doopdoop", "Text"], 150]];
Block[{withHiddenChanges = #2 &},
  modifyCellStyles[
   Cells[cd, CellStyle -> "Text"], 
   Replace["Text" -> "Item"]
   ]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
NotebookClose[cd];

{13.1319, Null}

cd = CreateDocument[ConstantArray[Cell["doopdoop", "Text"], 150]];
modifyCellStyles[
  Cells[cd, CellStyle -> "Text"], 
  Replace["Text" -> "Item"]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
NotebookClose[cd];

{7.19384, Null}
```

For the case at hand the batch edits actually work fastest:

```
cd = CreateDocument[ConstantArray[Cell["doopdoop", "Text"], 150]];
modifyCellStylesBatch[
  Cells[cd, CellStyle -> "Text"], 
  Replace["Text" -> "Item"]
  ] // AbsoluteTiming
NotebookClose[cd];

{3.64923, Null}
```

Comment: Why not `cd=CreateDocument[ConstantArray[Cell["doopdoop","Text"],150]];
AbsoluteTiming[NotebookPut[NotebookGet[cd]/.Cell[c_,"Text",o___]:> Cell[c,"Item",o],cd]]` ? Takes less than half a second. Sure, this gets slow if the notebook is huge, but in general the Mathematica Kernel is much more efficient in replacing stuff than any FrontEnd (undocumented) tools.

Comment: That's another option, just not in the vein I prefer to work. The big thing I usually want it something that won't lose my selection and, if possible (it wasn't here), doesn't destroy the `CellObject` I'm working with. Similarly, the `NotebookPut` method loses where you were in the notebook.

Comment: Sure. If only the whole standard FrontEnd would have been written, designed and maintained better. In real-life situations (generating large reports e.g.) it is nearly unusable.

Answer (score 5):

Here is another one:

```
PromoteStyles // ClearAll
PromoteStyles[] := PromoteStyles @ EvaluationNotebook[];
$defaultOrder = {"Title", "Chapter", "Subchapter", "Section", "Subsection", "Subsubsection"}

PromoteStyles[ nb_NotebookObject,  stylesOrder : {__String} : $defaultOrder ] := ( 
  PromoteStyle[nb] @@@ Reverse @ Partition[Reverse@stylesOrder, 2, 1];
);

PromoteStyle[nb_NotebookObject] := Function[{old, new}, PromoteStyle[nb, old, new]]
PromoteStyle[nb_NotebookObject, old_, new_] := Scan[
  ( SelectionMove[#, All, Cell, AutoScroll -> False]
  ; FrontEndTokenExecute[nb, "Style", new]
  ) &
, Cells[nb, CellStyle -> old]
];
```

And you can run `PromoteStyles[]` or `PromoteStyles@nb`